# Black Hole challenge from codewars

Tags: code-golf, matrix

I came across this challenge from codewars. I wish to know how to solve this problem. The problem description is given below.

Its elements are in range[1..n^2]. The matrix is filled by rings, from the outwards the innermost. Each ring is filled with numbers in the following way:

1. The first number is written in the top left corner;
2. The second number is written in the top right corner;
3. The third number is written in the bottom right corner;
4. The fourth number is written in the bottom left corner;
5. Each next number is written next to the number written 4 steps before it,
   until the ring is filled.

The matrix is constructed when all numbers are written.```
Given the size of the hole, return the number written at (`a, b`) - you may use any consistent indexing, but please specify if (`a, b`) is anything other than 0-indexed and row-major.

## Example

For `n = 4, a = 1, b = 1`, the output should be `13`.

The hole looks like this:

```
[ [  1,  5,  9,  2 ] 
  [ 12, 13, 14,  6 ] 
  [  8, 16, 15, 10 ] 
  [  4, 11,  7,  3 ] 
] 

The element at (1, 1) is 13
```

#### Test cases

(`a, b`) is 0-indexed and row-major here.

```
n   a   b   result
1   0   0    1
2   0   0    1
3   0   0    1
4   0   0    1
2   0   1    2
3   0   1    5
3   1   1    9
4   1   1   13
4   2   1   16
5   2   3   22
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  As it stands your question is lacking a crucial component that we require of all questions, an "objective winning criterion".  That is, an objective way to score answers.  The most common one is [tag:code-golf].

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic, Hi When I heard about Programming Puzzles and Code gulf, I thought it's about asking a programming challenge and getting a solution to it. Am sorry, am new to this site. I don't know 'Objective winning criterion'

Comment: If you want an easy winning criterion, the majority of the questions on this site are tagged as [tag:code-golf], meaning that the winning criterion is the least bytes.

Comment: @senox, Yes. Thanks for helping me. I would go with least bytes as winning criterion

Comment: May we instead take 1-indexed indices `[a,b]` (i.e. top-left is 1st row, 1st column, so `[1,1]` ...and your example `13` would be at `[2,2]`)?

Comment: Please ping me when you've addressed @JonathanAllan's question and I'll cast my vote to reopen. Welcome to PPCG, by the way :) Nice first challenge. For future reference, we have a [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/58974) where you can post challenges for community feedback and iron out any issues before posting them to Main.

Comment: Does codewars allow their challenges to be posted on other sites?

Comment: @JoKing. Am sorry, I dont know.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Sounds good.

Comment: Thanks, I made an update - it's best to edit the post accordingly rather than leaving specifications in the comment section - please check you agree with it.

Comment: @JonathanAllan. Now I agree with 1-indexed array. So do I need to edit the (a,b) values ?. Since it is 1-indexed array, [a,b] starts from [1,1].

Comment: I edited to *allow* other indexing, but kept zero-indexing and row-major (top-bottom; left-right) as the default (hence why I added the sentence above the test cases too) if you click "edited ... mins ago" you can see the diff.

Comment: If you're going to accept an answer at all, then at least accept the one that is actually winning by the winning criterion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>120</s> <s>119</s> 90 bytes

```python
def f(n,a,b):n-=1;A,B,C=min((a,b,1),(n-b,a,2),(n-a,n-b,3),(b,n-a,4));return(n-A)*4*A+4*B+C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc3NCoMwDAfw@56isEvrIqwfDjbxoD6JZcqELZOuHvb0XdRRkCEr/CH5NSTD29@eqEK4th3rOEIDVlwwLWReQgV18eiRc0KQAjimlgbUXDUwdZpqC1NnhMhd60eH9FmKxCTlwSTVoQ57tjykNBRLce1rvPvd4Hr0dFcCY8cpgtG0jK42XG@4@bNHzq5@9iyerVxGP6/2R5d65Sr6KXr2dT25UuED)

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 87 bytes

```python
def f(n,a,b):A,B=min((a,b+1/4),(n+~b,a+.5),(n+~a,n-b-1/4),(b,n-a));return(n+~A)*4*A+B*4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc3NCsIwDAfwu09R8NKundqPCSoetjdpccOBxlG7gxdfvbZ2bAwZBv6Q8AtJ93LXB0jvL3WDGgxMM0OOJavO9xYwDhPlW0UYBvo2TNNNkXrNIDd5IhN6TcjJ1q63ELUkmcpKWmXKr1EqCNEhJg62fvY3t@psCw43mDOEdjGEoLDPRxBLIJdA/TvFE4ifUwMUM@ATHGY/JuByBmKC/QjFAPILQvgP)

Returns a float

<sub>-3 bytes, thanks to Arnauld</sub>

---

#### Explanation:

This takes advantage of the fact that there is some symmetry to the matrix.

The matrix can be split into four quarters, which are equal when rotated (+ an offset of 1-3).

[image]

The first part `A,B,C=...` finds out which quarter the current coordinates are in, by finding the smallest coordinates, relative to each quarter:

[image]

(green: `(a,b)`, yellow: `(n-b,a)`, red: `(n-a,n-b)`, blue: `(b,n-a)`)

The coordinate pair is then converted to a value:

`(0,0) = 1`, `(0,1) = 5`, and so on; each coordinate is `4` larger than the previous.

`sum((n-(i*2))*4for i in range(A))` skips the rows above, `+(B-A)*4` moves along the row, and `+C` adds the offset.

`sum((n-(i*2))*4for i in range(A))+(B-A)*4+C` is shortened to `(n-A)*4*A+4*B+C`

Comment: it's interesting, the question seems to imply the input is always an even number, but your algorithm works for odd as well?

Comment: @donbright The testcases have both even and odd numbers?

Comment: lol oops!  my bad

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>36</s> <s>31</s> <s>28</s> 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
<αìRDÀsā)ø{н`Š4*ŠD¹<α4**O
```

Port of [*@TFeld*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181396/52210), so make sure to upvote him!
-3 bytes thanks to *@Emigna*.

Inputs are \$n\$ and \$[a,b]\$.

Uses the legacy version instead of the new 05AB1E version, because there seems to be a bug with the sorting (`{`) of multidimensional lists.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f5tzGw2uCXA43FB9p1Dy8o/rC3oSjC0y0ji5wObQTKGeipeX//78pV7SRjnEsAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWVCWGikS8R/m3MbD68JcjncUHykUfPwjuoLexOOLjDROrrAJQIoZaKl5f9f5390tKFOtIGOQWysjkK0EYJpjGCaoCkwRCiAMw2hTBMUphGUaQpiGsOYBjomMKYJMtMAodYoNjYWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
<          # Decrease the (implicit) input `n` by 1
 α         # Take the absolute difference with the (implicit) input-list
           #  (we now have `[n-1-a, n-1-b]`)
  ì        # Prepend the input (we now have `[n-1-a, n-1-b, a, b]`)
   R       # Reverse the list (we now have `[b, a, n-1-b, n-1-a]`)
DÀ         # Duplicate this list, and rotate it once towards the left
    s      # Swap these two lists
ā          # Push a list in the range [1, length_list] without popping the list: [1,2,3,4]
     )     # Wrap all three lists into a list (we now have 
           #  `[[a, n-1-b, n-1-a, b], [b, a, n-1-b, n-1-a], [1, 2, 3, 4]]`)
      ø    # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns (we now have
           #  `[[a, b, 1], [n-1-b, a, 2], [n-1-a, n-1-b, 3], [b, n-1-a, 4]]`)
       {н  # Get the minimum by sorting the lists and getting the first inner list
           # (since the minimum builtins in 05AB1E flatten multidimensional lists
           #  and give a single integer)
`          # Push all three values to the stack: `A`, `B`, and `C`
Š          # Triple-swap once, so the order is now `C`, `A`, `B`
 4*        # Multiply `B` by 4
Š          # Triple-swap again to `B*4`, `C`, `A`
 D         # Duplicate `A`
  ¹<α      # Take the absolute difference with `n-1` (so basically `n-1-A`)
     4*    # Multiply that by 4
       *   # Multiply it with the duplicated `A`
O          # Sum all values on the stack (`B*4 + C + (n-1-A)*4*A`)
           # (and output the result implicitly)
```

Comment: `<αRIRì` can be `<αìR` and `4L` can be `ā`.

Comment: @Emigna I'm an idiot.. I tried some things with append, prepend, and rotates, and eventually ended up with what I had. Two reverses and a prepend.. Why not just prepend first and then reverse.. dohh.. Thanks! Oh, also thanks for `ā`. I always forget about that builtin for some reason..

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 28 bytes

```
³_1ị’;1×4
’0;_ⱮpƝẎAµżJṂFµæ.Ç
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT8AwP9qZWxsef//wrNfMeG7i@KAmTsxw5c0CuKAmTA7X@KxrnDGneG6jkHCtcW8SuG5gkbCtcOmLsOH////Nf8yLDM)

Based on [@TFeld’s python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181396/42248) so be sure to upvote that one too.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 86 bytes

```javascript
(w,y,x)=>[x+(Y=w+~y)*y,y+(w+=~x)*x,w+Y*y,Y+w*x][k=x<y?x>Y?2:3:x<Y?0:x>y?1:Y-y&&2]*4-~k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc3dCoIwHAXw@57CK9ncTDc1SJw@xxAvxDJK0cho/9346iZ9IGVIcK7OD8455be8Ky7H89Vu2t1@KMWAFNUUsIhTIEgKRXqNLU01QYqIHrAFVBE5NpIoC7K0EhDpBGKZ8NALIZKJG0KsExZKW5smzyzf7quhaJuurffruj2gEjFquGMwNhzHMNjqU/mieovq/7HMXsp/Lr81mCubdDv/nZR5c@WTbr40eKj3VM6HOw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ZUẎTḢṬ_Ʋṁ
+þ`ṠÇƬSœị@
```

A dyadic Link accepting `n` on the left and `[a,b]` (1-indexed) on the right.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATQAy/9qZWxsef//WlXhuo5U4bii4bmsX8ay4bmBCivDvmDhuaDDh8asU8WT4buLQP///zj/Mywy)**

#### How?

```
ZUẎTḢṬ_Ʋṁ - Link 1, next matrix (rotated): current matrix
Z         - transpose          }
 U        - reverse each row   } -> rotate clockwise 1/4
  Ẏ       - tighten into a flat list of values
       Ʋ  - last four links as a monad:
   T      -   truthy indices -- e.g. [0,0,1,0,1,1,0] -> [3,5,6]
    Ḣ     -   head (empty list yields 0)             ->  3
     Ṭ    -   un-truth (0 yields an empty list)      -> [0,0,1]
      _   - subtract (vectorises)                    -> [0,0,0,0,1,1,0]
        ṁ - mould to shape of the current matrix again

+þ`ṠÇƬSœị@ - Main Link: integer, n; list of integers [a,b]
  `         - using left (n) as both arguments:
 þ          -   table of (implicit range of integer arguments)
+           -     addition
   Ṡ        - sign -- now we have an n by n matrix of ones
     Ƭ      - collect up (a list of matrices) while results are different with:
    Ç       -   last Link (1) as a monad
      ¬     - logical NOT (replace the 1s with 0s and vice-versa)
       S    - sum (vectorises)
          @ - with swapped arguments:
        œị  -   multidimensional index into
```

Answer (score 0):

## Rust - 340 bytes

```
fn f(n:usize,x:usize,y:usize)->usize{let (mut r,d)=(0,(n-1)&1);for l in ((1+d)..=n).step_by(2) {let (mut i,m,mx,mut z)=(0,l/2,n/2,0);loop {z=4*i+n*n-l*l;let u=[mx+m-i-d,mx-m,mx+m-d,mx-m+i];if (x,y)==(u[0],u[1]){r=z+4}if (x,y)==(u[2],u[0]){r=z+3}if (x,y)==(u[3],u[2]){r=z+2}if (x,y)==(u[1],u[3]){r=z+1}i+=1;if i>=l-1{break};}}r}
```

still got some work to do, but it basically draws the whole spiral, centered on a point in the middle, and saves the value at requested point x,y.

[ungolf spiral draw at play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0aa0d8e4f9a26a73742241f2c70a6f27)